# Is there some string-like format I can use that would encapsulate what is in a GIS file?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, vector

I'm running comparisons to find if there was a change in data. I'm using GeoTIFF and GPKG files (GeoTIFF will be compared to GeoTIFF and GPKG will be compared to GPKG). I have a database with information on each file.

Rather than having to pull the actual files and compare files directly to see if there is a difference in the data (not necessarily what the actual difference is, just if there is one or not). I would like if there was a way to just store some unique textual representation of what's in the file in a database than I can just compare that to see if there is a change.

Is this possible in anyway and what would be the best approach? Is there a way I can represent a GeoTIFF or GPKG in a string and that string could represent with precision what is in the GeoTIFF/GPKG file?

Comment: You could use asc or xyz for the rasters and geojson or wkt for the vectors but I don't feel like this approach is going to do you any good. What is your actual problem and goal?

Comment: Simply that I'm going to be performing a lot of comparisons and the performance increase of not having to retrieve file locations from the database, retrieve the actual files, and compare the files would result in higher efficiency. If I can just pull a string value from the database to do the comparisons, it will reduce time significantly I presume with the amount of comparisons I'll be doing.

Comment: If you store all the data as string in a database for comparison you effectively duplicate your data (and probably increase its size by magnitudes). But that would enable you to properly compare the data all within the database once imported. I still do not understand what goal you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Just improving performance on comparisons.

Comment: A text format of your geo data will be slower than the original format in pretty much all cases.

Comment: "Just improving performance on comparisons." — but why? If you have all this information in a database, it begs the question of why you're distributing copies of the same file around to people to edit them, only to have this work of manual reconciliation.

Comment: It's a daily update on given areas. The actual files are in a filesystem. Database just holds the metadata. And then the goal is iteratively go back for all previous days to see where the data for that area was different compared to the current processed day. I'm not sure I can realistically do that on an actual file to file comparison given the potential scale. So my hope was for a slicker, less intensive way to accomplish the same thing through storing a text equivalent of the file as metadata in the database and just doing a query on matching values. I'll look more into md5sum.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to compare files for *any difference* then you can use generic tools that have no relation to GIS as such. I would calculate an [md5sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum). If the files are identical, then the MD5 hash will be the same. If they are even *slightly* different, the MD5 hash will be completely different.

Since you've tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python), see this question for detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431825/generating-an-md5-checksum-of-a-file

Comment: The stress on *slightly* different is important. Even if field order in a table is different, you'll get a different hash.

Comment: I was thinking more of a GIS approach because I wanted it to work similar to how QGIS would compare the two files. I was concerned that with a more generic approach, maybe like @Fezter mentioned that unimportant details such as order or maybe system/file metadata unrelated to the GIS aspects could have an effect. Not sure what all the cases could be that might affect a hash.

Comment: I think if you actually mean "not necessarily what the actual difference is, just if there is one or not", then an MD5 sum is the way to go. Even if the change is "unimportant" it seems to me that your goal would be to eliminate candidates that are _definitely_ identical. What you do with the remainder is harder, but this at least cuts out a lot of things you don't have to compare in more detail. That is, it should at least be a component of your solution.